# Matrix Equality - Bellman

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question**: Use the relation $|AB|=|A||B|$ to show that $$(a_1^2+a_2^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2)=(a_1b_1-a_2b_2)^2+(a_2b_1+a_1b_2)^2.$$

**Attempt**: It's easy to expand out the two sides to verify they are equivalent, but I don't understand how the hint comes into play here? Bellman denoted matrices by capital letters in the exposition, but I would assume here that we'd want $A$ and $B$ to be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Any help appreciated - thanks.

**Source**: Bellman - "Introduction to Matrix Analysis"

Comment: What is the definition of $|A|$ for a matrix $A$?

Comment: I believe $|A|=\sqrt{A^TA}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe $|A|$ is used to denote the determinant of $A$ in this case. The matrices you are looking for are given by $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ -a_2 & a_1  \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \\ -b_2 & b_1  \end{pmatrix} . $$
Using $|AB| = |A||B|$ for these matrices results in the identity you want.

This representation of $(a_1, a_2)$ by $A$ is actually a a way to represent complex numbers using real matrices. Equivalently, you could define $z_a = a_1 + a_2i $, $z_b = b_1 + b_2i $, and use the identity $|z_az_b| = |z_a| |z_b|$, where $|z|$ is the norm of the complex number $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Whoops - that is much more sensible - appreciate it!